# Inconsistent results from R-part package

Tags: r, rpart

I am running R part on the same data set but the order of the columns are different and I am getting different results.

This is my dataset

```
   Home.Owner Marital.Status Annual.Income Default
1         Yes         Single           125      No
2          No        Married           100      No
3          No         Single            70      No
4         Yes        Married           120      No
5          No       Divorced            95     Yes
6          No        Married            60      No
7         Yes       Divorced           220      No
8          No         Single            85     Yes
9          No        Married            75      No
10         No         Single            90     Yes
```

This is the code

```
a<-read.csv("ab.csv")
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
model1<-rpart(Default ~.,data =a,method = "class",minsplit = 1,minbucket = 1 
              ,parms=list(split=c("information") ))

rpart.plot(model1)
```

results:

[image]

```
#changing column order 
b<-a[,c(4,3,2,1)]

# running same process
model2<-rpart(Default ~.,data =b,method = "class",minsplit = 1,minbucket = 1 
              ,parms=list(split=c("information") ))

rpart.plot(model2)
```

[image]

The only thing that has changed is the order of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here. This happens and I can explain why.

Notice that the two trees are different from the very first split. That is what we must understand.  `rpart` uses [Gini Impurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity) to decide which variable to use to split the data. One time it used `Marital Status` and the other it used `Annual Income`. Look carefully at what happened in each split.  When it split on `Marital Status`, it created two nodes one with 40% of the data and no errors. The other node had 60% of the data and 50% errors. When it split on `annual income`,  it produced exactly the same distribution: one node with 40% of the data and no errors; the other node with 60% of the data and 50% errors.   Both of these two splits produce the same Gini impurity. It is a tie between the two attributes. So `rpart` makes an arbitrary choice between the two.  It picks the first one, hence the dependence on the attribute order.